# android - overlap a button over another

Tags: android, button, android-relativelayout, overlap

how can i overlap a `Button` over another inside `RelativeLayout` ?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7DGr.png)

Thanks.

Here is what i've tried. Thanks

```
   <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/category"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/btn2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/btn1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/btn2" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you can try adding to btn2 a negative left margin

Comment: You can give margin to the second one and also apply to_rightof property to second one based on first one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do it by setting the margin to a negative value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"/>
            <ImageView android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-20dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

this is how you can achieve it.
use `layout_margin` attribute for the button on right and give it a negative value.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/category"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="MyLargeBtn" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="SmallBtn" />
```